# Clipping issues with gameobjects driven by transform.translate

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a game object that I am moving in the X/z plane using transform.translate. I'm using transform translate because I want tight control over the direction and speed of the object, while also being able to use Rigidbody.addforce() for jumping and allowing other rigidbodies to collide with it and transfer momentum.

The issue is unlike when I use velocity methods for movement, the gameobject will clip through solid objects like walls since the transform is being forced forward.

Is there any way to get the transform method to act like the velocity method or alternatively is there a way to use Velocity movement while still having tight control over things like rotation speed and direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do **not** use `Transform` when dealing with physics - it will break collision detection and behave unnatural/undesired.

If you still want strict control but interact with the physics scene rather use [`Rigidbody.MovePosition`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html) and [`Rigidbody.MoveRotation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MoveRotation.html)